# Visualize Neural network

Tags: python

Whenever I try to visualize my network by using the command below

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')
```

I get an error message saying

> > `pydot` failed to call GraphViz.Please install GraphViz (https://www.graphviz.org/) and ensure that its executables are in the $PATH.""

though I have installed GraphViz earlier, the error is due to some path problem, that I am unable to fix.
I am new in python coding.
help needed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS are you using? Where have you installed GraphViz? What does your `$PATH` look like…?

Comment: After changing $PATH$, reboot

Comment: `os.environ["PATH"] = ...` in your program body to add GraphViz installation directory to the path could be an ad interim solution, but it's not portable and you should be able (in different ways, depending on your OS) to modify the environment BEFORE  running your script.